# GUI library for multiplatform C# development

Tags: c#, gui, user-interface, mono

(I was redirected here from Stack Overflow it seems that the question is more on-topic here?)

I am searching for a GUI library for our project which is written in C# and uses Mono for cross-platform support (CLR for Windows, Mono for Linux and Mac). Most of the information on the net, for example here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gui-toolkits/ has gotten old.

Our criterion is:

- Native C# or up-to date C# bindings
- Docking support readymade or easily implementable
- Has a good design (or if it does, like GTK, easily themeable)
- Possible to have an OpenGL context in the same window with the GUI. (Currently we are using https://github.com/garrynewman/GWEN this library for GUI. It allows us to create a context and have GWEN to draw the GUI into it, and then draw to the context ourselves whatever we want. A viewport-style thing would be fine too.)
- It would be great to have a DirectX context too.

We considered QT because it's well known and modern but it doesn't seem to have up-to date and stable C# bindings. GTK has something called GTK# so it could be a strong too. Then there's something called XWT, by the Mono developers but it isn't very well known.

Is there any other viable choices?

What are your experiences of these toolkits? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt seems to fit your requirements

- Has mono/.NET bindings called [QtSharp](https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp) (There are older ones referenced about on the web but this is the latest AFAIK)
- Has a docking example http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html you should be able to determine what is going on as the api is the same in c#
- OpenGL/DX definitely can do both (Have a search on the OGRE 3D forum, many people have done it there)
- Theming - https://forum.qt.io/topic/45959/styling-theming-qml-in-a-css-like-way

Answer (score 1):

[wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org) has .net bindings called [wx.Net](http://wxnet.sourceforge.net/binary.html) which are cross platform for MS.Net, Linux & Mac (Using Mono).

- Native look & feel
- Cross Platform
- Free (Libra & FLOSS)
- Not sure about OpenGL & DirectX contexts in the current version.

I personally have not used wx.Net but have used wxWidgets, (C++), and wxPython for years with a great deal of success.